# How many buffer objects can I bind to a target?

Tags: opengl

I am confused when I bind a vertex buffer object, whether the previous vbo is unbound or stay together with the newly bound vbo?

And what about other kind buffer objects? Where can I find some specification about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "kinds" of [Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object). A buffer object is an unformatted array of arbitrary data. Just as there are not "kinds" of `void*`'s, there are not "kinds" of buffer objects.

There are different [*uses* for buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#General_use), but these do not represent *separate* "kinds". You can use a buffer object as the [destination for a pixel transfer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object), then read the written data as [source vertex data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object). Then you can overwrite the buffer's data with a transform feedback output, then read the feedback data as a [texture to access in a shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture).

Buffer objects are very flexible.

As for the bind question, this is true of [all OpenGL objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object): when you [bind an object to a target](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Usage), anything that was previously bound to that target is unbound. So if you bind a buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, anything that was previously bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is unbound.